# How to create a plugin that stores the exception from a failing test

Tags: matlab, testing, plugins

I am running MATLAB R2014a and I'm running single tests with the command:

```
result = run(NameOfTestClass, 'NameOfTestMethod')
```

I can then find out if the test passed or failed by looking at the value of:

```
result.Passed
```

and

```
result.Failed
```

Is it possible that I can store in the result the reason that the test failed, and the stacktrace?

Would this be via writing a plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify the function in order to have access to the reason why it outputs a failed test. That should do it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - which function should I modify? `run` is a function that is built into MATLAB.

Comment: The function that you call with `run`.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB supplies the FailureDiagnosticsPlugin and the StopOnFailuresPlugin that you can use for this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tried the following:

`import matlab.unittest.TestSuite;`
`import matlab.unittest.TestRunner;`
`suite = TestSuite.fromClass(?NameOfClass);`
`plugin = matlab.unittest.plugins.FailureDiagnosticsPlugin;`
`runner = TestRunner.withNoPlugins;`
`runner.addPlugin(plugin);`
`result = runner.run(suite);`

Comment: which outputs the stacktrace and the reason the test failed to the Command Window but doesn't store it in the plugin, result or runner itself, as documented in the docs of the [FailureDiagnosticsPlugin](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.failurediagnosticsplugin-class.html).

Is there a plugin that can store the stacktrace and reason of the test failing as properties of an object (the plugin perhaps)?

Thanks